# Which tool for database vesioning to use? liquibase vs mysql binary logs

Tags: mysql, liquibase, database-versioning, database-deployment, binary-log

I'm trying to build a process of refactoring, testing and deployment of my databases. After some kind of research I found [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) as a nice tool for managing my database versions. As well similar kind of jobs could be done with just [mysql binary logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/point-in-time-recovery.html).

Could you tell me are there any benefits of liquibase above mysql binary logs?

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer liquibase over binary log . we have been using the same from 1 year and it been running smoothly .

Its easy to maintain the version of the data base using liquibase and even its also provide the way to rollback the changes to particular version.

even liquibase provide the way to track changes . it apply only those changes those changes have not been applied on database.

suppose your local database version is 3 and production data base version is 2 . then liquibase will only apply version 3 changes on production. it does not apply version 2 changes because its already has applied.